# Active Directory Security List

Tags: security, active-directory

Is there a way to make a Security List in Active Directory not also act as a Distribution List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Like distribution groups, security groups **can** also be used as an e-mail entity" ([Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781446.aspx))
Only if you attach an e-mail address to a group will it appear in outlook.

Right click > 'Exchange Tasks', there can you add or remove a group's e-mail address, has to be done on an Exchange Server.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A distribution group is only used by e-mail software and cannot be used when setting permissions.

A security group however can be used both for setting permissions and as a target for e-mail software. [To my knowledge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781446.aspx) this behavior cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create groups in AD, you have the choice of either making it a security group or a distribution group, but not both.